# Isomorphism - Linear Algebra ( someone check if my work is enough please)

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

[image]

I have a linear transformation $T: P_3\to \Bbb{R}_4$ defined by a matrix $A$

To show that $T$ is an isomorphism, is it enough to show that $T$ is a bijection by using $A$ to show that it is injective and then showing  $\text{Dim}(P_3) = \text{Dim}(\Bbb{R}_4)$. We conclude that $T$ is bijective and therefore $T$ is an isomorphism.

Can Anyone tell me if my work is correct please.

Comment: Can you explain how you are using $A$ to show that $T$ is injective?

Comment: We don't really have enough to know if your work is correct.  Presumably, your assignment is to prove that $P_3$ and $\Bbb R^4$ are isomorphic.  What is the linear transformation you're using?  It is enough to show that $T$ is a bijection **and that $T$ is linear**.  If you want feedback on your work, you'll have to give us more details.

Comment: Also, as long as you're finding the dimension of each space, you might as well use the fact that any two vector spaces of the same dimension are isomorphic.

Comment: I'm not sure if the matrix A is correct. I will post the exercise.

Answer (score 1):

Yes correct since in finite dimensional spaces and by the rank-nullity theorem we have for $f: V\to W$ with $\dim V=\dim W$:

$$f\;\text{injective}\iff f\;\text{surjective}\iff f\;\text{bijective}$$

Comment: So isomorphism is the same as proving that T is bijective right?

Comment: Yes: isomorphism means bijective linear transformation.